# Notation-what does $\text{res }f$ mean in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to read through my text on algebraic geometry but couldn't find where $\text{res }f$ is defined.

I think it's related to resultants but that would have at least two arguments.

Comment: Reference and context?

Comment: @RijulSaini Mumford, Complex projective varieties.

Comment: Context? Or maybe a page number?

Comment: @RijulSaini p44, 3.11, in Mumford's lemma. I couldn't find out where it is defined in the book.

Comment: It could mean "residue".

Answer (score -1):

It's just a restriction morphism.

Edit: Sorry I don't have a specific reference handy. I'd imagine any introductory material on sheaves would discuss it; failing that, it's bound to be early on in EGA or on the Stacks Project.